# How do I restore 1/2 of all files in a VSS image? aka Previous Version in bulk?

Tags: anti-virus, file-server, vss

Suppose I have many files that were virus infected in bulk.  It isn't the entire drive, but 1/2 of it.

I don't want to right click each folder and restore a previous version.  Is there a way to do Previous Version in bulk, or similar?

I found some tools for [Windows 2003 here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787108(v=ws.10).aspx), though I'm still looking for volrest and volperf and need to test on 2012 R2.

I also did find this SDK tool, [VShadow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530725(v=vs.85).aspx), and think I might be able to mount the shadow and work with that.

Am I going about this the correct way? What tool(s) should I use?

Comment: For 2008+ see [`diskshadow`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772172.aspx), for mounting in particular [`diskshadow expose`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731098.aspx). If you don't use a separate disk for VSS be aware [*"...high I/O load will cause shadow copies to be deleted..."*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753975.aspx)